# NodeJs - how to make function fs.writeFile write with BOM?

Tags: node.js, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I'm using nodeJS v0.8.6 and the native library fs. Here is my code :

```
var filesys = require('fs');
filesys.writeFile('test.txt', 'This is an example with accents : é è à ','utf8', function (err) {});
```

The problem is that it writes in utf8 without BOM (I use notepad++ to verify it) and it doesn't work in wordpad on Windows (the accents are not well displayed).  The thing is that I need that file to be well read by womeone using wordpad.

How can I add the BOM to my file ?

Answer (score 50):

UTF-8 doesn't require a bom, but you can add it by yourself of course.

```
filesys.writeFile('test.txt', '\ufeffThis is an example with accents : é è à ','utf8', function (err) {});
```

Comment: UTF-8 might not require a BOM in sane OSes and apps, but under Windows it just about always does. The exceptions are mostly cross-platform code ported from a sane environment.

Comment: Fixed an issue where I was sending a CSV file to the client, worked well on Unix-like, not on Windaube. This fixed it!

Comment: I'm writing a text/csv file and using 'utf8' explicitly with the BOM like here, but it still won't display correctly when I open the file in Excel (without the whole import process but only opening the file). Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

I elaborated on this answer in detail on this answer - [Adding UTF-8 BOM to string/Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879198/adding-utf-8-bom-to-string-blob/27975629#answer-27975629).

This is a very sparse answer that doesn't go into detail as to **why** this works.  The FEFF bytes are actually the UTF16LE BOM, so the previous answer is confusing.